# Entity Framework 6 Custom Relationship Convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have read [this](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions) documentation about convention in Entity Framework 6. But it does not contain convention for Relationship.

Suppose I have following model:

```
[TablePrefix("mst")]
public class Guru
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? IdKotaLahir { get; set; }

    public virtual Kota KotaLahir { get; set; }
}
```

I want property `IdKotaLahir` to be foreign key of navigation property `KotaLahir`.
Foreign key name is `"Id"+<NavigationPropertyName>`.
Is it possible using current version of entity framework (EF 6 alpha 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it just one property or you need this across the board (i.e. the whole model is using a convention where foreign key names are always "Id" + NavigationPropertyName)? If you just want the foreign key for a single entity you will be better off just using the `ForeignKey` attribute:

```
public class Guru
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? IdKotaLahir { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdKotaLahir")]
    public virtual Kota KotaLahir { get; set; }
}
```

This will work for both EF5 and EF6. In EF6 you can use custom conventions to configure foreign key properties. Here is custom convention I came up with:

```
public class NavigationPropertyConfigurationConvention
    : IConfigurationConvention<PropertyInfo, NavigationPropertyConfiguration>
{
    public void Apply(
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Func<NavigationPropertyConfiguration> configuration)
    {
        var foreignKeyProperty = 
            propertyInfo.DeclaringType.GetProperty("Id" + propertyInfo.Name);

        if (foreignKeyProperty != null && configuration().Constraint == null)
        {
            var fkConstraint = new ForeignKeyConstraintConfiguration();
            fkConstraint.AddColumn(foreignKeyProperty);

            configuration().Constraint = fkConstraint;
        }           
    }
}
```

I also wrote a more detailed [blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/03/24/my-first-encounter-with-custom-conventions-in-entity-framework-6/) on this.

Comment: whole model use that convention. So, it's better to use convention (if available) than using attribute or fluent API.

Comment: In this case using conventions makes sense. I updated the answer with a convention I came up with and wrote a blog post containing more details (the link is in the answer).

Comment: Btw, this answer no longer applicable to ef-6. They made `IConfigurationConvention` internal

Answer (score 3):

In EF6, the accepted answer's convention no longer works because IConfigurationConvention is internal. The way to handle this type of scenario is by inheriting from ForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention.

```
public class MyForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention : ForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention
{
    protected override bool MatchDependentKeyProperty(AssociationType associationType, AssociationEndMember dependentAssociationEnd,
        EdmProperty dependentProperty, EntityType principalEntityType, EdmProperty principalKeyProperty)
    {
        string navigationPropertyName = ((System.Reflection.PropertyInfo)dependentAssociationEnd.MetadataProperties.GetValue("ClrPropertyInfo", false).Value).Name;

        // The standard foreign key property to look for is NavigationProperty_PrimaryKeyName (e.g. "TableName_Id"). 
        // Use the below line to remove that underscore.
        //return dependentProperty.Name == navigationPropertyName + principalKeyProperty.Name;

        // Use the following for the IdKotaLahir scenario
        return dependentProperty.Name == "Id" + navigationPropertyName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are my hero. I've been needing this code for quite some time, but couldn't seem to find it.