# EF 6 Code First Migration with Conventions

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, conventions

I have referenced another SO question to rename my foreign key properties according to the convention I want.

[How do I remove underscore of foreign key fields in code first by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684555/how-do-i-remove-underscore-of-foreign-key-fields-in-code-first-by-convention)

What I am finding is that these conventions are only respected at runtime, and are not utilized when scaffolding code first migrations.

It would save me some time not having to tweak each migration generated if it would respected my FK naming convention.

For reference:

```
public class ApplicationUser : AbstractEntity
{
    public EmailAddress PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress : AbstractEntity
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Conventions.AddBefore<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>(new MyForeignKeyNamingConvention());
        mb.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); 

        //complex types here
        mb.Configurations.Add(new PersonNameConfiguration());

        //entity types here
        mb.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());
        mb.Configurations.Add(new EmailAddressConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(mb);
    }

    public IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

So for the entites above and the shown context I go to scaffold out the migration to add the email table.  It creates the following:

```
public partial class CreateEmailAddresses : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.EmailAddress",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Value = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 1023),
                    IsRemoved = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    CreatedDate = c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7),
                    ModifiedDate = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7),
                    RemovedDate = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        AddColumn("dbo.ApplicationUser", "PrimaryEmail_IdValue", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        CreateIndex("dbo.ApplicationUser", "PrimaryEmail_IdValue");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUser", "PrimaryEmail_IdValue", "dbo.EmailAddress", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUser", "PrimaryEmail_IdValue", "dbo.EmailAddress");
        DropIndex("dbo.ApplicationUser", new[] { "PrimaryEmail_IdValue" });
        DropColumn("dbo.ApplicationUser", "PrimaryEmail_IdValue");
        DropTable("dbo.EmailAddress");
    }
}
```

I tested at runtime however and the foreign key naming convention is indeed being used and functions how I want it to.  But the scaffolding portion of EF doesn't see it.

Am I simply over looking something?

*edit* To be clear I am wanting the migration to generate the foreign key names without the "_" in the name.