# foreign key naming convention and primary key naming convention affect each other - EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using this:

```
public class ForeignKeyNamingConvention : IStoreModelConvention<AssociationType>
{
    public void Apply(AssociationType association, DbModel model)
    {
        // Identify ForeignKey properties (including IAs)  
        if (association.IsForeignKey)
        {
        // rename FK columns  
        var constraint = association.Constraint;
        if (DoPropertiesHaveDefaultNames(constraint.FromProperties, constraint.ToRole.Name, constraint.ToProperties))
        {
            NormalizeForeignKeyProperties(constraint.FromProperties);
        }
        if (DoPropertiesHaveDefaultNames(constraint.ToProperties, constraint.FromRole.Name, constraint.FromProperties))
        {
            NormalizeForeignKeyProperties(constraint.ToProperties);
        }
        }
    }

    private static bool DoPropertiesHaveDefaultNames(ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmProperty> properties, string roleName, ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmProperty> otherEndProperties)
    {
        if (properties.Count != otherEndProperties.Count)
        {
        return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; ++i)
        {
        if (!properties[i].Name.EndsWith("_" + otherEndProperties[i].Name))
        {
            return false;
        }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void NormalizeForeignKeyProperties(ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<EdmProperty> properties)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; ++i)
        {
        int underscoreIndex = properties[i].Name.IndexOf('_');
        if (underscoreIndex > 0)
        {
            properties[i].Name = properties[i].Name.Remove(underscoreIndex, 1);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

to remove '_' in foreign key names:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<ForeignKeyNamingConvention>();
}
```

This works fine. However, I also want to concatenate the entity name with the Id so I use:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<ForeignKeyNamingConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
    .Configure(p => p.IsKey().HasColumnName(p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name + "Id"));
}
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I use:

```
modelBuilder.Properties()
        .Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
        .Configure(p => p.IsKey().HasColumnName(p.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name + "Id"));
```

Foreign key names contain '_' again. Why is this and how can I overcome this?

Comment: possible duplication for the question mentioned here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684555/how-do-i-remove-underscore-of-foreign-key-fields-in-code-first-by-convention

Comment: @HadiHassan no it is not - pls try to answer the question first.

Comment: check this article in which might help you http://imar.spaanjaars.com/588/prefixing-id-columns-with-the-table-name-in-entity-framework , almost the same as what you did but he recommended further instructions to be done, hope it will help you

Comment: That's where I took the code to combine Id with the entity name from. The problem is that as soon as I use this (see question) foreign keys contain _ again!

Comment: I think the problem is that you changed the name of the PK property with your `Configure` sentence and then the method `DoPropertiesHaveDefaultNames` in your convention always returns false because the names in `otherEndProperties` don't match with the expected ones, even when they contain the "_". You should set a breakpoint there and inspect the values of the properties. I'm not sure if the method `Apply` is executed before or after the `Configure` part when building the model.