# EF Code first column name for foreign key with underscore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Answer to question: I work out with my problem. And it differs from proposed duplicate question.

### The problem in my example is modificator "private" for fields. So EF don't know them and create columns by naming conventions.

Hereunder some properties of my model. In result of database generating some of columns have names with underscore (InternalWorkflow_Id) and other - without underscore (InitiatorId). Why? 
I can correct it by attributs or fluent api, but i dont understand why it go in that different way by default.

```
public Guid? ParentDocflowId { set; get; }
public Docflow ParentDocflow { set; get; }

public Guid InitiatorId { set; get; }
public Participant Initiator { set; get; }

public Guid RecipientId { set; get; }
public Participant Recipient { set; get; }

private Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
public Participant Owner { get; set; }

private Guid? InternalWorkflowId { get; set; }
public InternalWorkflow InternalWorkflow { get; set; }

private Guid StateId { get; set; }
public Type State { get; set; }

private Guid ClientAppId { get; set; }
public Type ClientApp { get; set; }

private Guid? ScopeVisibilityId { get; set; }
public Type ScopeVisibility { get; set; }
```

---

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.Docflows",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        WorkflowId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        Name = c.String(),
                        IsReviewed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        IsArchived = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        DateCreated = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        DateClosed = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        DateOff = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                        DocflowTemplateId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        ParentDocflowId = c.Guid(),
                        InitiatorId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        RecipientId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                        ClientApp_Id = c.Guid(),
                        InternalWorkflow_Id = c.Guid(),
                        Owner_Id = c.Guid(),
                        ScopeVisibility_Id = c.Guid(),
                        State_Id = c.Guid(),
                    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove underscore of foreign key fields in code first by convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684555/how-do-i-remove-underscore-of-foreign-key-fields-in-code-first-by-convention)

Answer (score 0):

I work out with my problem. And it differs from proposed duplicate question.
The problem in my example is modificator "private" for fields. So EF don't know them and create columns by naming conventions.