# Entity Framework: Specify foreign key constraint name

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is there a way how to specify a name of a foreign key constraint in Entity Framework (v6.1.3)? I mean actual name of DB constraint (like `FK_Books_AuthorId`), not to specify which column is the foreign key for the given navigation property.

I know you can do it for indices, like:

```
Property(x => x.AuthorId).HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
                new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Books_AuthorId")));
```

Is anything similar possible also for foreign key constraints?

Comment: Unfortunately no - see my answer to [Unique Indexes convention in EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186502/unique-indexes-convention-in-ef6)

Comment: Can you be more precises... Do you want to have a specific FK name for the constraint ( in DB ) or a specific FK Name in your table ? This is not the same

Comment: @OrcusZ I want custom FK name for the constraint in DB.

Comment: So @IvanStoev is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments and my further research, it is not currently (EF v6.1.3) possible to set custom name for database foreign key constraint.