# how to change auto generated "shadow properties" foreign key name for all entities?

Tags: entity-framework

i've a model like that

```
public class Class1 {
    public int identifier {get;set;}
}
public class Class2 {
    public int identifier {get;set;}
    public List<Class1> holders {get;set;}
    public List<Class1> users{get;set;}
}
```

my problem is the generated foreign keys in Class1 name are "Class2_identifier" and "Class2_identifier1" mean while what i want is "Class2_holders_identifier" and "Class2_users_identifier"

the real model is really huge so what i'm looking for is away to override how the names are generated in the "add-migration" step

Comment: Use Entity Framework's mapping.

Comment: @GertArnold i need some global configuration not handle each entity on its own .... i tried to use 
DbModelBuilder.Properties but didn't work as the generated columns dosn't have a property in the model

Comment: Thanks for adding your final code to my response! I hope you don't mind my editting.

Comment: @Diana: no problem good edit, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete implementation, just a hint: If you are using EntityFramework 6 you can define a custom model convention:

```
public class ForeignKeyNamingConvention : IStoreModelConvention<AssociationType>
{
    public void Apply(AssociationType association, DbModel model)
    {
        if (association.IsForeignKey)
        {
            var constraint = association.Constraint;
            // Implement your renaming code.
            // The data you need is inside association.Constraint.
        }
    }
}
```

And add it to your `DbContext.OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new ForeignKeyNamingConvention());
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18245172/1182515) contains some code that you can reuse (in this case the convention is used to remove underscores in the column names).

**Edit:** OP included their final solution here:

The problem as mentioned in **ef core "it's the same problem in ef6 but with no message**" console

> There are multiple relationships between 'Class1' and 'Class2' without configured foreign key properties causing EF to create shadow properties on 'Organization' with names dependent on the discovery order.

```
public class ForeignKeyNamingConvention : IStoreModelConvention<AssociationType>
{
    public void Apply(AssociationType association, DbModel model)
    {
        if (association.IsForeignKey)
        {
            var constraint = association.Constraint;
            // as i just needed the fk column name to be more clear 
            // "{entityName}_{propertyName}" which is provided in 
            // {association.Name}
            association.Constraint.ToProperties[0].Name = association.Name;
        }
    }
}
```