# Entity Framework 6 RTM - Custom Relationship Convention

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, convention

I was using a convention like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590977/entity-framework-6-custom-relationship-convention) in the beta version of EF6:

```
public class NavigationPropertyConfigurationConvention : IConfigurationConvention<PropertyInfo, NavigationPropertyConfiguration>
{
    public void Apply(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Func<NavigationPropertyConfiguration> configuration)
    {
        var foreignKeyProperty = propertyInfo.DeclaringType.GetProperty("Id" + propertyInfo.Name);

        if (foreignKeyProperty != null && configuration().Constraint == null)
        {
            var fkConstraint = new ForeignKeyConstraintConfiguration();
            fkConstraint.AddColumn(foreignKeyProperty);

            configuration().Constraint = fkConstraint;
        }           
    }
}
```

But with the IConfigurationConvention interface has been marked as internal, I can't upgrade my EF's references. Have searched by many places, but not found how to reproduce that functionality in the RTM version.

I have also tried [this](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1226), but seems only works with independent associations (IAs), what is not my case cause I have the FKs in CLR objects.

Has anyone done it works again?

Thanks!