# EF6 foreign key naming convention for "ID" + ForeignTableName

Tags: entity-framework-6

For some reason I have most of my foreign keys named like "ID" + ForeignTableName.
I can't figure out yet if this naming respects any of the foreign key naming conventions built into EF6.

If it does could someone please indicate the actual convention? If not I would very much appreciate some code to configure this convention into modelBuilder (to be more specific I saw [some examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164#introducing) on how to configure the primary key convention in the model builder **without** [creating another Convention class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592705/4419939), can it be done likewise for foreign keys?)

Comment: What's wrong with the link you have? Looks like what you want. The default convention is tablename + id.

Comment: Well is not wrong it's just I would like to know if there is a simpler way to configure a convention for foreign key, similar with the convention for primary key.